# How to navigate from a cell to the next cell in a row with out pressing back button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I designed an app that have a tableview cell  that contain a simple label in each cell. They are displayed in an other viewcontroller, but each time i want to see the next cell, i need every time to press the back button to go back to the tableviewcell and click the second cell etc... Do you know what function i can implement so i can navigate from a cell to the next cell in a row without going back to the tableviewcell, something like the  app mail. Hope guys could understand what i am struggling with :) .

I add an image in order to have a better understanding .Red is the way i take, in green is the way i want to take and green circle is the functionality i am thinking of.

Thank you !:) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1AQ5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a demo project. You can find it on:

https://appsint.nl/stackoverflow/NavigationDemoProject.zip

Basically this is what happens:

```
//retrieve the new ViewController
let detailViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as! DetailViewController
detailViewController.option = newOption

//manipulate the NavigationController stack
var currentViewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers
currentViewControllers?.removeLast()
currentViewControllers?.append(detailViewController)

//present the new stack
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(currentViewControllers!, animated: false)
```

Remember that this is only one implementation, there a are lots of other ways

Comment: Sure its not the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad question but it can be answered in a very general way.

When you tap a row on the table view and you move to the next view controller, you need to pass the same data model to the new view controller that you used to populate the table view. And you need to pass an index (or some other reference) to the specific value to display on the new view controller.

Then your up and down arrows simply refresh the data shown in the view controller with the previous or next record in your data model. You can disable the up arrow when you get to the first index and disable the down arrow when you get to the last index.